# Products are disabled after reindexing in magento2

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4.1

I having two websites with two domains are pointed to a shared IP address and managed in different folders with different login credentials, DB, Domains, c-panel, etc to each project.
Ex:
domain1: example1.com            home directory:home/example1
domain2: example2.com            home directory:home/example2

If I logged in to c-pnael and run reindex command to domain2 it will disable all the products in the domain1 and vice verse.

How this issue happen, How could we solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are connecting both websites to a single instance of Elasticsearch. Make sure you are pointing to different instances of ES for each of the Magento websites instance.